# Conducive perminant magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, molecular-dynamics

Can a permanent magnet be coiled to also double as a electromagnet? Could the current reverse or double the poles? The wire coil is made from a long thin magnetic bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Also you can coil wire around a nail to make an electromagnet and if the current is kept on for a sufficient time then the nail becomes noticeably magnetic. So being used as the core of an electromagnet can make a permanent magnet.